# For paginated queries that are sorted, is it best to cache the sorted result and paginate from that to improve efficiency?

Tags: sorting, caching, pagination

For pagination, every time a page is requested a sort has to occur on the whole dataset.

Is it wise to cache the sorted result on the backend and take a slice of it for each pagination request to improve efficiency?